# C# creating a report with charts

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I need to create a complex pdf with charts and etc..

I have tried html to pdf, not going with it.

I have looked at itextsharp, but i dont see to much docs on creating pdf charts.

Any suggestions?

I also thought maybe to create a DOC file and convert to pdf.

Comment: Could you explain why HTML-to-PDF approach is not suitable? A lot of javascript charts may be rendered to HTML and exported to fine-looking PDF documents. This is much easier than composing PDF with iTextSharp low-level API.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could generate a report with something like "Microsoft Reporting Services".
It does charts and it could export to PDF.
[SQL Server Reporting Services Advanced Charting](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/sql-server-reporting-services-advanced-charting/)

I would not use SAP CrystalReports (we had a LOT of troubles with subreports for example, and it is not intuitive for me).